# Getting no main manifest attribute,Maven Springboot

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I did saw multiple posts regarding this issue however none of them solved my issue.
I do have a spring boot maven based application and I am building a `war` file with that.

When I am using

```
java -jar target\App-0.0.1.war
```

I am getting `no main manifest attribute, in target\App-0.0.1.war`

However when I am using `mvn spring-boot:run`, i am able to run the application.

Thing is i need to deploy this app in `PCF`, and this is kind of failing in there with buildpack issue , i am guessing because of this.

POM.xml

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.tech.bar</groupId>
<artifactId>BarChainDemo</artifactId>
<version>${revision}</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>BarChainDemo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>****CONFIDENTIAL***</groupId>
    <artifactId>****CONFIDENTIAL***</artifactId>
    <version>****CONFIDENTIAL***</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    <revision>0.0.1</revision>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.15.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.15.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.5</version>
        <!--Adding exclusions and then below adding runtime as poms internal to jackson are mismatched -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you please post your pom.xml?

Comment: I am little confused about that weather I can do that or not . I think I should not because parent in that which I am using ja client specific

Comment: Then please post only that portion of pom.xml that you feel worth sharing.

Comment: Are you using JDK or JRE? By that, I mean is that if you go to `Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs`, JRE is selected or some JDK is selected?

Comment: It’s jdk but how does that matter? Just curious

Comment: I got the same issue earlier when I used JRE. Please make sure that while doing maven install, it is picking JDK and not JRE.